# Convert 2022-10-14T23:59:59-07:00 into unix time with spefcific dynamic timezone

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, timezone, unix-timestamp

Can someone please help me to write the python code to convert 2022-10-14T23:59:59-07:00 into unix time with dynamic timezone and also I want to know what does that -07:00 at the end indicates.

Comment: Some background on this format: [ISO 8601 on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Answer (score 3):

-07:00 means it's the time shown is a local time which is -7 compared to UTC.

```
from datetime import datetime
str_dt="2022-10-14T23:59:59-07:00"
dt=datetime.strptime(i,"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z")
unix_dt=datetime.timestamp(dt)
print(unix_dt)

>>>1665817199.0
```

unix is always UTC

this is your best friend:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html

Comment: [`fromisoformat`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromisoformat) might be useful in this context.